# Zend Framework :: extending action variable scope for partials

Tags: zend-framework, action, partials

I want to know if there exist any other way through which we can access the controller name, action name and other variables inside a partial. In other words, I want to extend the scope of my action variable to be accessed inside the partial templates rather than passing the lot along with the call to partial template.

Thanks
-DevD.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend your controllers to setup your necessary variables in the $view.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html

A controller plugin would be able to do the same.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html